# Alter uniqueidentifier primary key to be ROWGUIDCOL in SQL Compact 4

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to alter an existing SQL Compact 4 database to change the primary keys to be ROWGUIDCOL, and not succeeding.

The [SQL Compact ALTER TABLE documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174123%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) indicates you can use the ROWGUIDCOL. However, every variant of an ALTER TABLE that I issue fails:

- `ALTER TABLE Company ALTER COLUMN CompanyId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL`: Fails for invalid token: ROWGUIDCOL
- `ALTER TABLE Company ALTER COLUMN CompanyId ADD ROWGUIDCOL` (SQL Server syntax): Fails for invalid token: ADD
- `ALTER TABLE Company ALTER COLUMN CompanyId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL ROWGUIDCOL`: Fails for invalid token: ROWGUIDCOL
- `ALTER TABLE Company ALTER COLUMN CompanyId ROWGUIDCOL UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL`: Fails for invalid token: ROWGUIDCOL

From the documentation, the first command should have all the tokens in the proper order.

How do I set ROWGUIDCOL for an existing column in SQL Server Compact 4?

Comment: The documentation you linked to shows `ROWGUIDCOL` only in `<column_definition>`, which is used only with `ALTER TABLE ... ADD`. So that suggests it simply isn't possible with `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN`.

Comment: You can try to DROP the columns (and the contraints first) and then try to ADD them again. Maybe with a DEFAULT NEWID() if it is helpful in the situation.

Answer (score 2):

Here it is:

```
ALTER TABLE Company ALTER COLUMN CompanyId Add ROWGUIDCOL
```

Comment: My question shows that exact syntax (which is the T-SQL syntax for SQL server) and it does not work with SQL Compact.

Comment: @StefanSteiger but the question was about SQL CE specifically

Comment: @Saito Aren't those the same thing? Doesn't SQL CE stand for SQL Compact Edition?

Comment: @TomLint they are, but the problem is, SQL Server and SQL CE aren't the same thing. My comment is probably an answer to nowadays deleted comment